# Tick label overlaps axis label

Tags: javascript, chart.js

**ChartJS v2**

I am having a problem on small screen sizes (using the iPhone 5 screen emulator in Chrome) with my X axis tick labels overlapping my X axis label.

My Y axis label is also being cut off.

[image: Chart labels cut off]

I have tried playing around with padding and lineHeight for Label 2 to no avail. I have also tried setting the max / min rotation values for the X axis tick labels to 90deg which makes the issue worse.

The example in the screenshot above uses these settings:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: "bar",

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [
      "0k-40k",
      "40k-80k",
      "80k-100k",
      "100k-120k",
      "120k-160k",
      "160k-180k",
      "180k-220k"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
      }
    ]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            labelString: "Chart Label X",
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            labelString: "Chart Label Y",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

This looks like it is probably a bug in ChartJS not calculating the label heights correctly when rotated. Has anybody else had this problem? Is there a work around?

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/mayvoe

**GitHub Issue:** https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/5906

Answer (score 0):

In the end I had to compromise and shrink the font size, removing the x and y labels and updating the legend to provide the detail needed.

[image]

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: "bar",

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [
      "0k-40k",
      "40k-80k",
      "80k-100k",
      "100k-120k",
      "120k-160k",
      "160k-180k",
      "180k-220k"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My dataset x vs y",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
      }
    ]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: true
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            fontSize: 11,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 11,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/XoNVNe

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // The type of chart we want to create
  type: "bar",

  // The data for our dataset
  data: {
    labels: [
      "0k-40k",
      "40k-80k",
      "80k-100k",
      "100k-120k",
      "120k-160k",
      "160k-180k",
      "180k-220k"
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "My First dataset",
        backgroundColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        borderColor: "rgb(255, 99, 132)",
        data: [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45]
      }
    ]
  },

  // Configuration options go here
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            labelString: "Chart Label X",
            padding:{
              bottom: -5,
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          ticks: {
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            precision: 2,
            suggestedMin: 0
          },
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
            fontSize: 16,
            fontStyle: "bold",
            labelString: "Chart Label Y",
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Different browsers can render the canvas image in many different ways. Small screen devices are not an exception. You can try your code with different browsers on normal screen to assert your claim.

[image: chart1]

Chart.js have many options you can use for your code. i.e. You can use “Chart.bundle.js” or  “Chart.js” depending on your environment. The CSS you use can also affect how your chart is rendered on a canvas. The bundled build includes Moment.js in a single file. You should  use this version if you require time axes and want to  include single file.

*For example:*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
pcharts.html
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>P Charts</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/main.css">
        <script src="../lib/charts/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="../lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="../js/appcharts.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Charts</h1>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <div id="myCan">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br><br><hr><br><br>
    </body>
</html>
```

*appcharts.js*

```
/* 
 * appcharts.js
 * 
 */

var ctx;
var myChart;
var cdata = [0, 10, 5, 2, 20, 30, 45];
var lblX = ["0k-40k","40k-80k","80k-100k","100k-120k","120k-160k","160k-180k","180k-220k"];


function init(){
    render();
};

function render(){
    ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: lblX,
        datasets: [{
            label: 'My demo2 dataset.',
            data: cdata,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                ticks:{
                    beginAtZero:true        
                },
                scaleLabel:{
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Chart Label X."
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                },
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: "Chart Label Y."
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
};

//
//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $("#myCan").hide("slow");
//    $("#myCan").show("slow");
//});
//

window.onload = function(){
  init();  
};
//
//
```

[image: chart2]

---

Squeezing the big image in a small canvas is like squeezing big tomatoes in a small bottle. What will come out of that bottle is the tomato sauce and tomato seeds. Of course you can replant the tomato seeds if only and only if they are still OK. Orthographic projection do just that. You can render a big 
image in a small screen by using orthographic projection technique. e.g. Positioning of the camera or distortion determines what the viewer will see or look at.

When you are using charts you are actually drawing an image and rendering it on a screen for the viewer to look at. You can get the latest version of chart.js by using: `npm install chart.js  --save`  or download it from: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/latest  It comes with docs and samples.

To create a chart, we need to instantiate the Chart class. To do this, we need to pass in the node, jQuery instance, or 2d context of the canvas of where we want to draw the chart. Once you have the element or context, you're ready to instantiate a pre-defined chart-type or create your own.

Good luck.

---

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The chart uses a completely different configuration. If you have a solution, maybe fork this pen https://codepen.io/afisher88/pen/mayvoe and make an explanation to the updates that you made.

Comment: If your code is not working you can always debug it. The objective of writing the code, is to write the working program. I have written the working code example, just to do that. There are many technologies you can use to draw the image object. Some uses 2d and 3d. With 3d, you have to define X, Y and Z axis. You can also rotate, distort or transform the image. The tools you use are also important.